# How to check textarea vs CKEDITOR?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I need to capture last focused input and paste something in it later.

I've already managed to catch last focused HTML input field (using jQuery on focusin event) or CKEDITOR editor (using CKEDITOR API on focus event). Because I store this last object in one `var lastFocusedInput` (jQuery object or CKEDITOR editor object), now I need to determine if it is CKEDITOR or jQuery object, due to they have different methods to paste data in it.

Any ideas how to do this in a more sophisticated way than testing it like that:

```
function isjQueryObject(o)
{
    return (o && (o instanceof jQuery || o.constructor.prototype.jquery));
}

function isCKEditorObject(o)
{
    return (o && (typeof CKEDITOR !== undefined) && (typeof o.insertHtml !== undefined));
}
```

**EDIT on 2018-03-29**

In the meantime I've ended up with type testing as below due to the need of reuse in other areas of the code.

```
function TypeTester()
{
    var result = function (test)
    {
        return test ? true : false;
    };

    // jQuery [object Function]
    this.jQuery = function (o)
    {
        return result(o
            && (o instanceof jQuery || o.constructor.prototype.jquery)
        );
    };

    // CKEDITOR [object Object]
    this.CKEDITOR =
    {
        object: function (o)
        {
            return result(o
                && o.replaceClass === 'ckeditor'
            );
        },

        instance: function (o)
        {
            return result(o
                && o.insertHtml !== undefined
                && o.insertText !== undefined
            );
        },
    };
};
var isTypeOf = new TypeTester();

var lastFocusedInput = new Object(
{
    object: null,
    insert: function (content)
    {
        if (!this.object) return;

        switch (true)
        {
            case isTypeOf.jQuery(this.object) :
                this.object.insertAtCaret(content);
                break;

            case isTypeOf.CKEDITOR.instance(this.object) :
                this.object.insertHtml(content);
                break;
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: do you know the typeof object when you are storing?

Comment: @vinayakj Yes, I know it, but I don't want to add an overhead meta data.

Comment: then `o instanceof jQuery` is enough

Comment: Kinda, but I don't know if someone won't decide to change CKEDITOR to something else in the future. I would like to know what is it, if not a jQuery object.

Comment: then metadata is needed to keep track IMO

Comment: Yep, this way or another. BTW, I thought I'll find some reliable way to check if CKEDITOR is present. Testing API is kind of a daunting task.

Answer (score 1):

As you know the typeof object while storing then store it like

```
var lastFocusedInput= { type:'jQuery', theObject: theObjectToStore};
```

And access it like so

```
if(lastFocusedInput.type == 'jQuery'){
  //get jquery object -> lastFocusedInput.theObject
}else{
 //get CKEDITOR object ->  lastFocusedInput.theObject
}
```

Or use two containers

If object to store is jQuery

```
var $lastFocusedInput = theObjectToStore;
var CKElastFocusedInput= null;
```

or vice versa

while accessing

```
if($lastFocusedInput){// use jquery API on object }
else{ // use CKEDITOR API on object }
```